# How to know which screen is active if I use templates with PHP

Tags: php, session

I am using a template where the menu of my website goes, however I want to add the bootstrap active class to it so that the user knows which page he is on. At the moment the way I do it is the following:

Note that the "templates" file has several functions with an echo to display the html. Outside of the function that displays the HTML I call this option that PHP gives us.

```
$activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
```

Then I create a function to show the menu that looks like this, clearly it has more options, but to avoid putting so much code I only show this one.

```
function MostrarMenu(){
echo 
'
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link <?= ($activePage == about) active ?>" href="about.php">Sobre nosotros</a>
</li>
';
```

Then in the view I call this function so that it shows the menu

```
<?php MostrarMenu(); ?>
```

Comment: Your problem is that PHP code doesn’t run interpolated/embed like that. The simple solution is [string concatenation](https://3v4l.org/4q8j0), however it doesn’t scale well and most people would probably recommend a higher level structure such as an array that you could loop over instead.

Comment: Can i use this function to know what is the active page?? 

$activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");

Answer (score 0):

```
$activePage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

function MostrarMenu(){
$Active = ($activePage == '/about') ? "active": "";
echo 
'
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link '.$Active.'" href="about.php">Sobre nosotros</a>
</li>
';
}
```